# Add old top and bottom panels on Gnome 3 without downgrading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I am testing Ubuntu 11.10, I am using Unity so far but I am not 100% convinced I want to use this desktop. I also installed gnome 3, but I find Unity easier to use than gnome 3.

But I would like to use gnome because I believe I will be able to customize it better in the future. Plus I like that part of the code and extensions are in javascript. *What I would like is to have gnome 3 but with the old gnome 2 top and bottom panels.*

I tried tint2, but I don't love it, I would prefer to use the old gnome 2 panels if possible. I don't want to remove or modify anything else, just add the panels.

**Is that possible without downgrading?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cinammon](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Introducing-Cinnamon-The-GNOME-3-Replacement-244107.shtml) is a gnome-3 replacement that tries to restore many of gnome2's missing features, including the bottom panel but not the top one. I am not aware of any other gnome3 project that does a better job at restoring the old gnome behaviour.

Maybe this is enough for you?

Comment: I've end up using a few extensions but Cinammon looks cool I will try it out thanks.